# What is the equivalent of char* in VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have a third party DLL for which the documentation is for C++. I am calling it from VB.NET.

One of the structures that is used in a callback is defined as:

```
typedef struct  
{
    DWORD            dwOffSet;         // current picture file's offset in the binary file, byte
    DWORD            dwFileLenth;      // current picture file's size, byte
    WORD             wWidth;           // picture width, pixel
    WORD             wHeight;          // picture high, pixel
    char*            pszFilePath;      // File path
    int      nFilePathLen;          // File path Len of pszFilePath
}DH_PIC_INFO;
```

Is the VB.NET version (below) correct?

```
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure DH_PIC_INFO
        Public dwOffSet As UInt32 ' current picture file's offset in the binary file, byte
        Public dwFileLenth As UInt32 ' current picture file's size, byte
        Public wWidth As UInt16 ' picture width, pixel
        Public wHeight As UInt16 ' picture high, pixel
        Public pszFilePath As IntPtr ' File path
        Public nFilePathLen As Int32 ' File path Len Of pszFilePath
    End Structure
```

Apologies, the <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> line should not have been there.

I was intending to use:

```
Marshal.Copy(stPicInfo.pszFilePath, stringPictureFileName, 0, stPicInfo.nFilePathLen)
```

However, I get a 0 for the nFilePathLen, so perhaps the IntPtr  type that I used is not correct.

Comment: When you say you get a 0, is the dll populating this structure?

Comment: Because C++ expects ASCIIZ, I _think_ it should be `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public pszFilePath As String>`, see [Default marshaling for strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings)

Comment: Yes, the DLL populates the structure. Also, I think I've made a mistake in the copy/paste; it's a largish struct and I had taken out the other parts. Lemme see... Removed. The MarshalAs line was supposed to be for a byte array.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but it looks like you need to use a StringBuilder which has its capacity already set to be large enough: [Call unmanaged C DLL with char pointer with VB.NET](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/372575-call-unmanaged-c-dll-with-char-pointer-with-vbnet/).

Comment: There is no one equivalent. Unfortunately, a C++ pointer can be a lot of different things, so you have to try to see what works and use the documentation for the original C++ struct.

Comment: I tried changing the definition to <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> Public pszFilePath As System.Text.StringBuilder but that results in a runtime error: System.TypeLoadException. The type definition of this field has layout information but has an invalid managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable.